# Target selector by href always firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to detect if an `a` tag contains just `#` in the `href` like so

```js
if ('#seller-shop[href*="#"]') {
  alert('I contain #')
} else {
  alert('I do not contain #')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="seller-shop" href="www.foo.bar">Seller Shop</a>
```

But for some reason it is always firing regardless of what is in the `href` what am I missing here?

Comment: Are you running this code on anchor click event?

Comment: Currently the href is being autopopulated from a outside database but occasionally it will load `#` as a placeholder url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) at this context,

```
if ($('#seller-shop').is('[href*="#"]')) {
  alert('I contain #')
} else {
  alert('I do not contain #')
}
```

Or you can do,

```
if ($('#seller-shop[href*="#"]').length) {
  alert('I contain #')
} else {
  alert('I do not contain #')
}
```

Or you can use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) over the `href`,

```
if (document.getElementById("seller-shop").href.includes("#")) {
  alert('I contain #')
} else {
  alert('I do not contain #')
}
```

Your code is not working, since a non-empty string will always evaluates to `true`

```
if ('#seller-shop[href*="#"]') {
//--^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---- This is a simple string.
```

Comment: Simple `indexOf` is also sufficient.

Comment: I seem to be getting `Unexpected string` errors if i use either of these

Comment: Ahhh now its working well this seems to be the simplest way of doing it. Do you know the reasoning why my original code wasn't working shouldnt it still just select by `#`?

Comment: Perfect all of these are good answers but this one seems to be the most in depth for me

Answer (score 1):

Try this :Read href value and compare it with `"#"`

```js
var hrefVAl = $('#seller-shop').attr('[href*="#"]');
if (hrefVAl=="#") {
  alert('I contain #')
} else {
  alert('I do not contain #')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="seller-shop" href="www.foo.bar">Seller Shop</a>
```

Comment: OP wants to check if exactly `#` there, said "a tag contains just # in the href". IndexOf will give be overhead in that case.

Comment: This answer seems to be perfect for my case, Do you know the reasoning why my original code wasn't working?

Comment: You have put string in if condition which does not evaluate to true or false and hence always going in else block. You can use `$('#seller-shop[href="#"]').length` in if condition which gives you 1 if href="#" means true value otherwise in else part.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in your snippet `'#seller-shop[href="#"]` is a string is always evaluated to `true`

Further `$('#seller-shop[href="#"]')` returns an object that will also yield to `true`. Use `length` property to check weather selector matches any element.

```js
if ($('#seller-shop[href="#"]').length) {
  alert('I contain #')
} else {
  alert('I do not contain #')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="seller-shop" href="www.foo.com">Seller Shop</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `href` attribute

```
if($('#seller-shop').attr('href')=="#"){
  alert('Only #')
} else {
  alert('Other than #')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

USING JAVASCRIPT ONLY:

```
window.onload = function () {
var element =  document.querySelector('#seller-shop[href*="#"]');
if (element != null)
{
 alert('I contain #');
}
else {
  alert('I do not contain #');
}
}
```